# JWT authentication using httponly cookie with Spring Boot and Angular 5

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, jwt

So, I am developing an **Angular 5** app, which requires authentication. Angular app is retrieving data from **Spring Boot** API. For authentication I send email and password to API which, if correct, sends me back JWT token.
I have read that storing token in localStorage is not a good idea, because it is accessible with javascript and therefore vulnerable to attacks. Therefore I want to store JWT into cookie with **httponly** and **secure** flags.

However, the problem is because Angular app and Spring Boot app are running on different origins and therefore response received from Spring cannot set cookie.

I want to know how to achieve that when login is successful my API sets cookie for angular application which may live on another domain.

Here is my Authentication Resource:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> loginUser(@RequestBody LoginRequest request, HttpServletResponse res) {
        LoginResponse response = new LoginResponse("this_is_my_token");
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token", "this_is_my_token");
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setSecure(true);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        res.addCookie(cookie);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
    }
```

I have also configured CORS filter:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer cors() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200") //current angular host, later will be changed
                        .allowCredentials(true)
                        .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

Then in my Angular app I have this service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginSerivce {
    private headers: HttpHeaders;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
        });
    }

    public getToken() {
        const data = JSON.stringify({
            email: "test",
            geslo: "Test"
        });
        this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/v1/auth/login",
            data, {headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true})
            .toPromise()
            .then(
                (resp) => {
                    console.log(resp);
                },
                (err) => {
                    console.log("error: ", err);
                }
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this exact same issue. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: yes, in my case the problem was in setSecure(true), which requires https, otherwise cookie is not set (and in development i dont use https)

Comment: then how did you test it in development

Comment: @sneha I used a flag from config to tell me whether i am in dev environment or production (flag set during startup) and if i was in dev mode i didn't set setSecure(true), if i was in production i did.

Comment: @MihaJamsek: When you send back a request to the back end with `withCredentials: true`, are you able to decode the token in the back end ? see my question here : [decode httponly cookie recieved from front end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66965054/how-to-decode-credentials-sent-using-withcredentials-true-from-angular-cookie)